# How to mount Android as CD-ROM?

Tags: android, bash, mount, cd-rom

I have Galaxy S4 with custom ROM and kernel. I need to mount ISO image from sdcard to Windows/Linux PC as CD-ROM. 
There's a "DriveDroid" app that works fine, but I need to do it manually (as a study). Windows 8 writes that "Device needs to be formatted".
code (bash script)

```
# Disable USB
echo 0 > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable

# Set Vendor and Product IDs
echo 0x04e8 > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/idVendor
echo 0x6860 > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/idProduct

# Set mass_storage mode
echo mass_storage > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/functions

# Enable CD-ROM and make read-only (ERROR HERE!)
echo 1 > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/f_mass_storage/lun0/cdrom
echo 1 > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/f_mass_storage/lun0/ro

# Set path to ISO
echo /mnt/shell/emulated/0/obraz.iso > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/f_mass_storage/lun0/file

# Enable USB
echo 1 > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable
```

However, both `cdrom` and `ro` files are still set to 0. What else should I do to make them "1" ?

Comment: Is there any error being displayed? Permission error, invalid file... - Anyway, try `chmod +w /sys/class/android_usb/android0/f_mass_storage/lun0/cdrom`, same for the other file.

Comment: @ShellFish, no, no errors displayed. Script works out fine, however `cdrom` is 0 (instead of 1), so Windows 8 gives dialog box "To use disk in F:\ format it first"

Comment: @ShellFish, `cdrom` file has -rw-r--r-- rights and is owned by root (from which I'm calling script)

Comment: Maybe something is overwriting it? Try to add `cat /sys/class/android_usb/android0/f_mass_storage/lun0/cdrom` right after you set it? Or `echo $?` to check the exit code?

Comment: @ShellFish shows 0 both before trying to set 1 and after it.

Comment: @ShellFish that's very strange, because after using DriveDroid once, I'm able to write 0 and 1 to `cdrom`, but without first using it, I'm not able o_O

Comment: There must be something overwriting the value, maybe try to write the value in a later stage.

Comment: @ShellFish OK, I'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before writing 1 to "cdrom" and "ro" I had to empty "file" file.
Thanks @FrozenCOW (Developer of DriveDroid) for help!

```
# Clear path to ISO
echo "" > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/f_mass_storage/lun0/file

# Enable CD-ROM and make read-only (ERROR HERE!)
echo 1 > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/f_mass_storage/lun0/cdrom
echo 1 > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/f_mass_storage/lun0/ro

# Set path to ISO
echo /mnt/shell/emulated/0/obraz.iso > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/f_mass_storage/lun0/file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Disable USB
echo 0 | tee /sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable

# Set Vendor and Product IDs
echo 0x04e8 | tee /sys/class/android_usb/android0/idVendor
echo 0x6860 | tee /sys/class/android_usb/android0/idProduct

# Set mass_storage mode
echo mass_storage | tee /sys/class/android_usb/android0/functions

# Enable CD-ROM and make read-only
echo 1 | tee /sys/class/android_usb/android0/f_mass_storage/lun*/ro

# Set path to ISO
echo | tee /sys/class/android_usb/android0/f_mass_storage/lun*/file
echo <YOUR-IMAGE-FILE-PATH> | tee /sys/class/android_usb/android0/f_mass_storage/lun*/file

# Enable USB
echo 1 | tee /sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable
```

It is work on my phone. (Asus T00F - android 7.1.2)